# Is it legal to put ads in an Android app that uses libspotify?

Tags: android, spotify

I am aware that the nature of this question is not programming related, however, Spotify customer service simply redirected me to the support section of the developer site, and I have not received a response on IRC.

After reading through the terms of use several times (https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/terms-of-use-us/), it seems that it is not legal to charge for an app that uses libspotify or charge for it, but I am trying to make sure.  Is there anyone from Spotify who knows the answer for sure?  Or is there a forum for which this question is more appropriate?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a legal issue.

Comment: Right, as I mentioned I contacted someone via this form (https://www.spotify.com/us/about-us/contact/contact-spotify-support/?contact) and the person was unable to redirect me to the developer team after asking for that.  He just showed me the developer support site (https://www.spotify.com/us/about-us/contact/contact-spotify-support/?contact) which only has this site and IRC which I am also trying to get an answer on.

I may have to try the contact form again to see if I get someone else that can help.

Comment: IANAL, but section 3.3 of that agreement seems to very clearly disallow advertising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer your Question.

In fact nobody who is not an employee of Spotify can answer your Question.

And probably a Spotify employee who is reading this cannot answer your Question because:

- he / she is not on top of these issues because he / she is a developer, not a lawyer or someone involved in the business side of Spotify, and / or
- he / she has been instructed to NOT answer Questions like this.

A Spotify developer providing public answers to questions like this could put the company in an awkward position if there ever was a legal dispute about the way some person / company was using Spotify services.  (And that need not be a dispute involving you ...)

Your best options are to persist with your attempts to contact Spotify through support and other channels.  If you don't get satisfaction by those routes, employ a lawyer to give you a legal opinion based on the Terms of Use ... and the relevant law.

---

> .... and the person was unable to redirect me to the developer team after asking for that.

That is not surprising.  The developer team are not the right people to answer legal questions ... or questions that relate to the Spotify business model.

Comment: I appreciate the honest, but still helpful response!

Comment: Just as an update for anyone who finds this later, I was able to get a response from an employee:

I forwarded your question to our Platform team who owns libspotify and their reply was this:
"This is not allowed today under our non commercial TOUs."
----------------

And that was in response to: "My question is whether it is legal to make an Android app that uses libspotify which also has ads in it (or is a paid app)."